# _CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey when using PogoConnect SDK

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am using a SDK that include the Pogo Connect SDK. When I add the SDK and build I get some errors. Then I have imported the AVFundation and CoreBluetooth libraries.
Before add the CoreBluetooth library I get this errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", referenced from:
      -[T1PogoPenConnectionManager startScan:] in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1PogoPenConnectionManager.o)
  "_CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey", referenced from:
      -[T1PogoPenConnectionManager initWithDelegate:sender:] in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1PogoPenConnectionManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBUUID", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1PogoPenConnectionManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1Peripheral.o)
  "_CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey", referenced from:
      -[T1PogoPenConnectionManager connectT1Peripheral:] in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1PogoPenConnectionManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBCentralManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1PogoPenConnectionManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But after add this library I still get this errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey", referenced from:
      -[T1PogoPenConnectionManager initWithDelegate:sender:] in SealSignBSSClientLibrary.a(T1PogoPenConnectionManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked for a solution but I have found that this "CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey" is inside CoreBluetooth library.

Any suggestion??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you get is because you are trying to compile your project for iOS 6 where Core Bluetooth doesn't have the `_CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey` enum and Pogo probably uses that. You must change to iOS 7 or remoe the dependency to that SDK.

Comment: sorry @allprog, yes, I tried using the iOS 7 SDK and works fine, thank u!